# Saving generated .wav file to server with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, wav

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stream a WAV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551943/how-to-stream-a-wav-file)

I am developing a website where users can compose their own music, and the site will generate a .wav file for their creation.  This is working correctly (inasmuch as I can play it on the page).  However, I would like to save this file to the server to be listened to/downloaded at a later time, and the saved version of the file can no longer be opened and played by the HTML audio tag.

What, if anything, must I put into the file besides the file besides the raw data?  Instead of setting the src attribute of the audio tag to the location of the file, will I actually need to open it and generate a URI?

At the moment, what I'm doing to play the wav file looks like this:

```
wav = [headerChunk, fmtChunk, dataChunk].join(''); 
var URI = "data:audio/wav;base64," + escape(btoa(wav));
document.getElementById("player").setAttribute("src", URI);
```

To save this, I'm just writing 'wav' directly into a file; I then try to play it back by setting the audio tag's src to be the location of that file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, in an ideal world you will need to post the file with JQuery, but I don't think you have the file as you think you do, (you may do, but it's not really likely, there are too many security walls around things) it's much more likely that you a) have a Java Object with the file in it, or b) (**much** more likely) a flash object with the music in it.

In which case it's this "Box-of-tricks" that needs to be told to post it: i.e. if you are in browser client with a music file as a physical file then you probably downloaded it, if you edited/created it in the browser somehow you probably have a flash object with it in memory within -- in which case getting flash to post it is your only way

Comment: `wav = [headerChunk, fmtChunk, dataChunk].join('');
var URI = "data:audio/wav;base64," + escape(btoa(wav));
document.getElementById("player").setAttribute("src", URI);`

These are the lines that we're using to set the src attribute (the rest of the file generation is up above, filling those chunks).  We've been simply trying to write the vsariable 'wav' into a file; will this not actually give us what we want?

Comment: I can see what you are doing. Somehow you have the object as jQuery you might be able to byte post it with jQuery (EG: $('#player').val(); will exist in jQuery) but you'll be very lucky, I am interested as to how you got this far, I have never heard of anything like this being done to be honest.

Comment: I am all out of useful ideas, you're going to have to do some heavy lifting of your own, the nearest thing to this I have ever done is reassemble an image to a byte stream with a "user editor" it did work but it was like trying to rebuild everything in the dark mostly by guestimating

Comment: Did I just read "ideal world" and jQuery in on sentence?