# PCM Audio to File

Tags: java, discord, pcm, discord-jda

I want to record audio in a Discord Voice Channel and save it to a file using a Discord Bot.

I receive the Audio every 20 milliseconds as an pcm-encoded byte[], that I want to save to a file.
MP3 is prefered but I don't have problems with other file formats like ogg (It may be easier) too.

I am using JDA version `4.ALPHA.0_82` and I also included lavaplayer version `1.3.17` for other features. It would be helpful, if these libraries are anough, but it's no problem if I have to include more.

Comment: I dump the PCM into a file and send it back through discord to hear it. Granted, the files are massive, but it works :^) Also note that JDA gives you PCM data, not opus (unless they changed something in v4)

Comment: I thought of the same approach, isn't there an easy way to save it in an compressed audio format?

Comment: I once got told to pipe it through ffmpeg. I'm assuming you want a cross-platform/self-contained solution though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652746/convert-pcm-raw-bytes-to-wav-bytes) explains how to convert pcm to wav.
I copied the Discord audio into a `List<byte[]>` by overriding the Method `AudioReceiveHandler#handleCombinedAudio`:

```
private List<byte[]> rescievedBytes=new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public void handleCombinedAudio(CombinedAudio combinedAudio) {
    try {
        rescievedBytes.add(combinedAudio.getAudioData(VOLUME));
    }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        //close connection
    }
}
```

After that, I copied the `List` into a `byte[]` and created the `wav` file.

```
try {
        int size=0;
        for (byte[] bs : rescievedBytes) {
            size+=bs.length;
        }
        byte[] decodedData=new byte[size];
        int i=0;
        for (byte[] bs : rescievedBytes) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bs.length; j++) {
                decodedData[i++]=bs[j];
            }
        }
        getWavFile(getNextFile(), decodedData);
    } catch (IOException|OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private void getWavFile(File outFile, byte[] decodedData) throws IOException {
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000, 16, 1, true, false);
    AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
            decodedData), format, decodedData.length), AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outFile);
}
```

In case that the rescieved audio gets too big (`OutOfMemoryError`) the conversion is aborted.

Comment: You forgot to increment i.

Comment: Why didn't you use the format provided by the [AudioReceiveHandler](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/ac3f1a78355bb3cb799dd91adb62432b1473978c/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/api/audio/AudioReceiveHandler.java#L32)?